# Why is ArgumentParser object giving None value even though arguments are being passed through shell script

Tags: python, sh, argparse

I am calling a python script in a shell script and passing arguments to this python job. Arguments are being loaded from a config file. The variables being called are correctly echoed when testing in the shell script. The HIVE_ labelled arguments are all being marked as None in the argument parser.

Shell Script

```
set -e

if \[ ! -z "$1" \]
then
config_file="$1"
else
config_file="./env.sh"
fi

${venv_path} ${mpw_path}/src/main_sample.py \
\--MPW_BASE "${mpw_base}" --MPW_PATH "${mpw_path}" \
\--FUNC "${trueup}" --TRUEUP_FILE "${trueup_file}"  \
\--TRUEUP_FILE_MANUAL "${trueup_file_manual}" --LATEST_TRUEUP_STAMP "${latest_trueup_stamp}" \
\--SQL_driver "${SQL_driver}" --SQL_server "$SQL_server" \
\--SQL_port "${SQL_port}" --SQL_db "${SQL_db}" \
\--LANDING_ZONE "${landing_zone}" --TIME_STAMP "${time_stamp}" \\ 
\--HIVE_driver "${HIVE_driver}" --HIVE_host "${HIVE_host}" \
\--HIVE_ZKNamespace "${HIVE_zknamespace}" --HIVE_ServiceDiscoveryMode "${HIVE_servicediscoverymode}" \
\--HIVE_AuthMech "${HIVE_authMech}" --HIVE_KrbServiceName "${HIVE_krbservicename}" \\ 
\--HIVE_KrbHostFQDN "${HIVE_krbhostfqdn}" --HIVE_SSP_tezqueue "${HIVE_ssp_tezqueue}"
```

Config File

```
HIVE_driver=""
HIVE_host=""
HIVE_zknamespace=""
HIVE_servicediscoverymode=""
HIVE_authMech=""
HIVE_krbserviceame=""
HIVE_krbhostfqdn=""
HIVE_ssp_tezqueue=""
```

Config variables values are missing for obvious reasoning

Python Script

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='MPW Arg Parser')
    parser.add_argument('--MPW_BASE', help='base directory of project') 
    parser.add_argument('--MPW_PATH', help='directory of the repo') 
    parser.add_argument('--FUNC', help='function to done')
    parser.add_argument('--TRUEUP_FILE', help='mapping to be passed in writecustomertrueup') 
    parser.add_argument('--TRUEUP_FILE_MANUAL',  help='trueup exercise of previous week')
    parser.add_argument('--LATEST_TRUEUP_STAMP', help='trueup stamp') 
    parser.add_argument('--SQL_driver', help='SQL Driver') 
    parser.add_argument('--SQL_server', help='SQL Server') 
    parser.add_argument('--SQL_port', help='SQL Port') 
    parser.add_argument('--SQL_db', help='DATABASE to connect')
    parser.add_argument('--LANDING_ZONE', help='Landing zone of MPW')
    parser.add_argument('--TIME_STAMP', help="time stamp") 
    parser.add_argument('--HIVE_driver', help='EDL Driver') 
    parser.add_argument('--HIVE_host', help='EDL Host') 
    parser.add_argument('--HIVE_ZKNamespace', help='EDL ZKNamespace')
    parser.add_argument('--HIVE_ServiceDiscoveryMode', help='EDL Service Discovery Mode') 
    parser.add_argument('--HIVE_AuthMech', help='EDL Auth Mech') 
    parser.add_argument('--HIVE_KrbServiceName', help = 'KrbServiceName') 
    parser.add_argument('--HIVE_KrbHostFQDN', help = 'For EDL connection') 
    parser.add_argument('--HIVE_SSP_tezqueue', help = 'For EDL connection') 
    
    
    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()    
    
    if args.MPW_BASE is None or args.MPW_PATH is None or args.FUNC is None \
    or args.TRUEUP_FILE is None or args.TRUEUP_FILE_MANUAL is None \
    or args.LATEST_TRUEUP_STAMP is None or args.SQL_driver is None \
    or args.SQL_server is None or args.SQL_port is None or args.SQL_db \
    is None or args.LANDING_ZONE is None or args.TIME_STAMP is None \
    or args.HIVE_driver is None or args.HIVE_host is None or args.HIVE_ZKNamespace \
    is None or args.HIVE_ServiceDiscoveryMode is None or args.HIVE_AuthMech \
    is None or args.HIVE_KrbServiceName is None or args.HIVE_KrbHostFQDN is None \
    or args.HIVE_SSP_tezqueue is None:
    

      logging.error(str(args))
      logging.error(str(unknown))
```

Error for args:

```
22/11/21 13:16:02 ERROR \<module\> Namespace(FUNC='TRUEUP', HIVE_AuthMech=None, HIVE_KrbHostFQDN=None, HIVE_KrbServiceName=None, HIVE_SSP_tezqueue=None, HIVE_ServiceDiscoveryMode=None, HIVE_ZKNamespace=None, HIVE_driver=None, HIVE_host=None
```

Error for unknown:

```
22/11/21 13:16:02 ERROR \<module\> \[' '\]
```

I tried to change the variable names in the config and the shell script files and am expecting it to read the arguments correctly but still get None value for the HIVE_ named variables.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to *source* the config file, because none of the shell parameters are defined.

Comment: Your shell script is also littered with backslashes that it doesn't need.

Comment: It might help to look at the `sys.argv`, just to see what the `parser` has to work with.

Comment: @hpaulj I printed the sys.argv on the terminal it seems that the arguments get cut off after TIME_STAMP is passed, any recommendations

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't do anything with the config file, just stores its name/path in a variable. The config needs to be read in order to use the values.

```bash
set -e

if [ ! -z "$1" ]
then
config_file="$1"
else
config_file="./env.sh"
fi

. "${config_file}"
```